# Should I use dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know this question is dumb. But suddenly got stuck up with this question.

When I use **dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier**, the cells are reused. To be more specific, first 'n' set of cells is reused - along with their **references**

As the same references are reused, I can't actually store local variables to the cells. I actually need to assign them everytime in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Assume I'm using a custom complex UITableviewcell. (I know we should reduce complexity. But still...)

Some views are to be added to the cell.

Best example i could think of is an image slider.

So the number of images in the image slider differs based on the datasource. So i need to add the views in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Can't avoid it.

Since the same reference of cells are reused, I need to add these views everytime cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. I think that is a bit of heavy load.

I thought of using **drawRect** method, but it does not work with **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

If I don't use dequeReusableCell, I will have individual referenced cells, but it will cost the memory and performance.

So what is the best solution?
Can I use dequeReusableCell and still need not rewrite its content?

Edit 1: 
By mentioning dequeReusableCell, I did mention dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier - forIndexPath. I'm sorry for the confusion.

**Edit 2:** 
**I feel, I'm not so clear in my question.**

**Lets consider I have a array in my viewcontroller.**
**I'm configuring my cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier - forIndexPath**

**So what happens is, everytime i scroll, when the invisible rows become visible, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.**

**Lets say I have a image slider with n imageviews. For each cell, this 'n' differs. So I'm forced to draw the cell's view based on its dataSource.**

**So everytime the tableView calls cellForRowAtIndexPath, the cell is configured again and again.**

**I want to avoid this to improve performance.**

Comment: Don't save references. Every time when you need reference to *visible* cell at `indexPath` - call `if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {}`

Comment: I hope cellForRowAtIndexPath no more returns nil. So this check is of no use. Correct me if wrong

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` return `nil` if cell at `indexPath` is not visible or `indexPath` is out of range.

Comment: If you build your cells differently, consider using different reuseIdentifiers. (And use custom subclasses if possible). If they all need to be configured completely from scratch anyway, don't reuse the cells, just create a new one (I think passing *nil* for the identifier will do the job).

Comment: Don't (ab)use the cells as the data source.

Comment: Is your image slider horizontal? If I were you, I would share a screenshot, so people know what it looks like.

Comment: @Eiko Passing nil/ using different resuseIdentifiers is same as not using dequeReusableCell. And without using reusable cells, you will end up in a very heavy memory load causing performance issues

Comment: @MartinR I'm sorry. But I don't get you.

Comment: @ayteq That is just an example. A scenario that I can think of. But if it helps, yes lets say its a horizontal slider.

Comment: @Shob-Z: You are mixing "model" and "view". Don't store the information in the cells. Store it in the model, e.g. an array of structs. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, configure the cell from the array data. (Which is what ddb suggested).

Comment: @MartinR I'm not concentrating on storing data in the cell's class. As you say, I have this separate array of structs. I configure the cell. But this cell gets configured every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. And I want to avoid it. It should be configured only once. So how do i check that?

Comment: @Shob-Z Sorry, I don't get your intention. It seems you are mixing up things here. Drawing cells is a different matter than reusing cells. You absolutely need to configure a cell before using it. There's just no way around it. What is your *actual problem*?

Comment: @Shob-Z: It seems that I (partially) misread your question, so forgot about my previous comments. – A concrete example (with code) would be helpful in order to suggest possible better solutions.

Comment: @Shob-Z check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

Comment: @MartinR - I have edited the question.

Comment: @ayteq Nope. Doesn't help. Im not concentrating on drawing a horizontal slider. Im here to understand dequeReusableCell

Comment: "I want to avoid this to improve performance." Are you sure? Did you measure? You cannot configure without ... hmm... configuring. I'd think changing the number of elements is the cheapest part. Changing image contents has the potential to be expensive. But then, there is obviously no way to lose this step. If your configuring is really expensive **and** can be reused sensible, give each such configuration a unique identifer and you're done. That's exactly what this concept is designed for.

Comment: Thanks @Eiko. You are right. There is no better solution

Answer (score 1):

what I do in this case is the following:

1. I always use `dequeReusableCell:`, for reasons you already said
2. I write a `cleanCell` method in the custom `UITableViewCell` class in order to clean everything has been already set on the cell (just to make it ready for reuse)
3. then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I configure my cell as desired

Comment: Yeah, I do the cleaning part in prepareForReuse method. I'm just asking, if there is a way to maintain the cell's datasource.

Comment: @Shob-Z, what do you mean with "*maintain*"?

Comment: Ok. For example, I have a variable myData to the custom UITableviewcell. Now I set this myData value for a particular cell in a indexpath. I set another value for another cell in a different indexpath. When the cells are reused, the second cell's myData will return you first cell's myData. This forces us to set the variable everytime we call cellForRowAtIndexPath. We cannot maintain the value! I'm not sure if i'm clear enough.

Comment: well, in this case "*maintain*" and "*reuse*" are two opposite thinking theories. In this cause what I'd do is to *maintain* the array of data in the viewController that handles the tableViewController and continue with the reuse technique when handling its cell

Comment: sorry, @Shob-Z, maybe I didn't, I hope I helped anyway :) I'm here if you want to comment anymore

Comment: I'm not concentrating on storing data in the cell's class. As you say, I have this separate array in my viewcontroller. I configure the cell. But this cell gets configured every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. And I want to avoid it. It should be configured only once. So how do i check that?

Comment: A cell does not have a data source.

Comment: Each custom cell have built-in method  ""prepareForReuse"" , which you need to implement, to prepare cell to reuse, and don't need to build own wheel.
In cell *.m file.

Comment: @Shob-Z, what you're trying to do is outside iOS developers architecture. In my opinion you should avoid it. Also maintaining in memory a complete slider (I don't know how many slides with images you have) is an out-of-memory risk for your app. Anyway when a cell will get visibile, iOS will call the cellForRowAtIndexPath, even if you don't want

Answer (score 1):

That's what I would do: I would move the logic of adding those heavy views inside the cell's class itself. So that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I would just set an object that has to be displayed inside the cell, and cell would create all the necessary views on its own (it's a view layer, after all). So inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it would look something like this:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...forIndexPath...];
cell.modelObject = myModelObject;
```

and that's it.

Then inside the cell class I would implement optimizations for switching between different model objects. Like, you could defer releasing the heavy views, and reuse them, when the cell is reused.

To be honest, I don't get your example with the slider, but let's suppose you have a star rating with 5 stars, which can be visible or not. There are various way to do it, but let's assume you're just adding / removing a `UIImageView` for each star. The way you do it now, you would have an empty cell and create / add views in `cellForRow`. What I'm suggesting is to have 5 `UIImageView`s as part of your cell, and inside the cell set their visibility based on the `modelObject.rating`. Something like that. I hope, it helps to illustrate my point :)

**UPDATE**: when your cell can have an arbitary number of images inside of it, I would probably create them inside the cell's class. So, for instance, for the first model object we need 3 image views. So we create them. But then we don't release them in `prepareForReuse`, we wait for the next model object to come. And if it has, say, 1 image, we release 2 image views (or we don't, so that we didn't have to recreate them later, it depends on what is more critical: performance, or memory usage), and if it needs 5, we create two more. And if it needs 3, we're all set already.

Comment: This is a better alternate. I will consider this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method. This method automatically decides whether the cell needs to be created or dequeued.

> I need to add these views everytime cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. I think that is a bit of heavy load.

You don't need to add those views every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called. Those views should be already added as a cell is instantiated. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you only assign images and other values to those views.

In case if you use storyboards and prototype cells your code should look like this:

```
var items = [UIImage]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    let recipient = item.recipients.first

    // I have given my UIImageView tag = 101 to easily access it from the view controller.
    // This allows me to avoid defining a custom UITableViewCell subclass for simple cells.
    if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UIImageView {
        imageView.image = item
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: 1. Yes i'm using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
2. Imagine you have n number of imageviews. This 'n' differs for each cell. So I cant fix a defnite number of views while the cell is instantiated. I need to both create views and assign images in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Shob-Z got your problem now. In this case it's probably better to have another `UITableView` within a cell.

Comment: I'm trying to lessen the load! Adding another tableview/collectionview will increase it more.

Comment: @Shob-Z Huh? Don't you think that manually handling subviews is better than have another UITableView? :) But probably you should consider to revise the UX/UI.

Comment: Sounds fair. But are you sure it won't loaden it up? I was thinking it will loaden it up. That is why handled the subviews manually.

Comment: But again. How will this solve my problem. I still need to configure the cell which has a tableview. It gets configured everytime cellForRow is called. My problem is to avoid configuring the cell everytime.

Comment: @Shob-Z since you have a cell with different appearance for each row, you have to reconfigure it. `UITableView` just takes a responsibility of handling subviews and it most likely will do that better than you. But definitely it would be better to measure the performance.

Answer (score 0):

1)I think you need to use "lazy load" of cells.
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-lazy-loading-images (for example)

2) You can create a property in your viewController, and create an NSMutableDictionary property, which will store the some data by the some key,
if your model have things like "ID" of the cells or you can use indexPath.row for it, then you can load it only one time, and next time when -cellForRow will be called, you can retrieve data from your dictionary by the

[self.dataDictionary objectForKey:@"cellID"];

And with this you, solve your repeating load.
In -cellForRow you can set the check,like.

```
if ([self.dataDictionary objectForKey:@"cellID"]) {
  cell.cellImage = [self.dataDictionary objectForKey:@"cellID"];
} else {
  UIImage *img = [uiimage load_image];
  cell.cellImage = img;
  [self.dataDictionary setObject:img forKey:@"cellID"];
}
```

And so on. Its like example, the dataType's you can choose by yourself, it's example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone helping me out. I think the better answer was from @Eiko.

When you use reusable cells, it must be completely reusable. If you are going to change its views based on the data, you either have to use a new identifier or avoid using reusable cells.

But avoiding reusable cells, will take a load. So you should either use different identifiers for similar cells or as @FreeNickName told - you can use an intermediate configuration and alter it on your need.